# How to write a an EF query involving a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm quite new to using the entity framework and I'm having trouble getting my head around how to write a query that uses a many to many relationship. I have 3 entities. **Role**, **User** and **Securable**. A **Role** can have multiple **Securables**, and a **Securable** can be assigned to many **Roles**. A **Role** can have multiple **Users**, and a **User** can have multiple **Roles**.

My Question is: **How would I go about writing a query that gave me a distinct list of Securables for a given user ID?**

Here is my model, where EF automatically creates the link tables for me.

```
public class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Securable> Securables { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string Forename { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Securable
{
    public Guid SecurableId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get;set;}
}

public class Role
{
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Securable> Securables { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but off the top of my head it would be something like this:

```
var context = new DbContext();
var result = context.Securables
                    .Where(s => s.Roles
                                 .Any(r => r.Users
                                            .Any(u => u.UserId = userId)))
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: This looks like a winner, I'll test it out tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
User user = ...;
IEnumerable<Securable> securablesForUser =
  user.Roles.SelectMany(x => x.Securables).Distinct();
```

**Update:-**

After working on a project where this was genuinely a performance bottleneck, I investigated more deeply and found that the following LINQ query generates the best SQL (for our data):-

```
IEnumerable<Securable> securablesForUser =
    context.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Roles)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Securables)
                 .Distinct();
```

This will use an `INNER JOIN` in the translated SQL wheras:-

```
IEnumerable<Securable> securablesForUser = context.Securables.Where(
    x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.Users.Any(z => z.UserId == userId))).Distinct();
```

uses `WHERE EXISTS` which in our benchmark was **slower** than querying twice.

As always, if you have performance concerns I recommend profiling. Results with your data may differ. **If you don't care enough to profile, you don't care enough to optimise!**

Comment: Hmm, simple solution, but I assume this will only work if lazy loading is enabled? Also this would require two sql queries, one to get the user, then a second to get the securables?

Comment: If it's a performance bottleneck, you could eager-load the Roles and Securables when you load the user. Unless you're displaying a list of users, though, I probably wouldn't bother.

Comment: No, this query works fine with no lazy loading. It would even work in EF 1. Eager loading won't help; it's fine as-is.